# retrieve pytest results programmatically when run via pytest.main()

Tags: python, pytest

I'd like to run `pytest` and then store results and present them to users on demand (e.g. store pytest results to a db and then expose them through web service).

I could run `pytest` from the command line with an option to save the results report into file, then find and parse the file, but it feels silly to have the results in a (pytest) python app, then store them to a file and then instantly look for the file, and parse it back into python code for further processing.

I know I can run `pytest` programmatically via `pytest.main(args)`, however, it only returns some exit code, and not details about test results. How can I retrieve the results when using `pytest.main()`?

I'm looking for something like:

```py
args = ARGUMENTS
ret_code = pytest.main(args=args)  # pytest.main() as is only returns trivial return code
my_own_method_to_process(pytest.results)  # how to retrieve any kind of pytest.results object that would contain test execution results data (list of executed tests, pass fail info, etc as pytest is displaying into console or saves into file reports)
```

There are couple of similar questions, but always with some deviation that doesn't work for me. I simply want to run `pytest` from my code, and - whatever format the output would be - directly grab it and further process it.

Note: I'm in a corporate environment, where installing new packages (i.e. pytest plugins) is limited, so I'd like to achieve this without installing any other module/pytest plugin into my environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write a small plugin that collects and stores reports for each test. Example:

```
import time
import pytest


class ResultsCollector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reports = []
        self.collected = 0
        self.exitcode = 0
        self.passed = 0
        self.failed = 0
        self.xfailed = 0
        self.skipped = 0
        self.total_duration = 0

    @pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
    def pytest_runtest_makereport(self, item, call):
        outcome = yield
        report = outcome.get_result()
        if report.when == 'call':
            self.reports.append(report)

    def pytest_collection_modifyitems(self, items):
        self.collected = len(items)

    def pytest_terminal_summary(self, terminalreporter, exitstatus):
        print(exitstatus, dir(exitstatus))
        self.exitcode = exitstatus.value
        self.passed = len(terminalreporter.stats.get('passed', []))
        self.failed = len(terminalreporter.stats.get('failed', []))
        self.xfailed = len(terminalreporter.stats.get('xfailed', []))
        self.skipped = len(terminalreporter.stats.get('skipped', []))

        self.total_duration = time.time() - terminalreporter._sessionstarttime

def run():
    collector = ResultsCollector()
    pytest.main(plugins=[collector])
    for report in collector.reports:
        print('id:', report.nodeid, 'outcome:', report.outcome)  # etc
    print('exit code:', collector.exitcode)
    print('passed:', collector.passed, 'failed:', collector.failed, 'xfailed:', collector.xfailed, 'skipped:', collector.skipped)
    print('total duration:', collector.total_duration)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly I needed! Each report in collector.reports contains traceback, captured stdout, duration, just all data. If I want to use this both from code and command-line, shall I keep it in some random .py file? I've read local plugins are to be stored into conftest.py, however it should not be explicitly imported into code

Comment: You can move the plugin class in a separate module or keep it alongside the code that calls `pytest.main()`, it depends more on your particular use case. Regarding the `conftest.py` - that's not your case here. Yes, conftest is a project-specific local plugin in a module file which should not be imported implicitly, pytest will do that for you. But here you have a plugin class - basically, `ResultsCollector` _is_ the conftest, only that you can place it wherever you want. That's the beauty of having plugins in classes instead of module files :-)

Comment: Got it tx. Is there any overall-run sum up object, and way how to capture it? I mean data like number of collected tests, overall duration, etc. The way its showed in cmd line \ console, or at the report generated with built in --junit option (there is root element testsuite which lists this) Expanding answer above, I've noticed I can also> if report.when == 'setup' to grab tests that are skipped or errorneous, however I'd prefer not to naively recreate any logic if pytest apparently already does this (but outputs it to console or file rather than returns when called from code as I need)

Comment: Sure, you need to implement more hooks though. E.g. `pytest_collect_modifyitems` grants you access to the collected tests count, and through `pytest_terminal_summary` you can access exit code of the test run and various stats that are printed in the summary. I have extended the example in the answer, check it out. You may also find other hooks useful - see their reference here: [Hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#hooks).